# How to configure htaccess for beta(subdirectory) keeping the root htacess as it is

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have live website in the root folder, now I have created a sub-directory to keep the development changes and test them on server, How Can I configure htaccess for subdirectory, I want to keep the live website running.

Currently my htaccess is as follows, similar to root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(member-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))/?$ team.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Please help me

**Edit** : I want to access beta site by just adding /beta at the end of the url. ex https://www.example.com/beta

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple `.htaccess` files

You should probably be OK by simply creating the same `.htaccess` in your sub-directory and just removing the `RewriteBase` command - it really isn't needed in most cases, and except when rewriting paths to files on the document root, configuring it correctly can be quite confusing.

Here is a sample setup:

```
+- DOCROOT/index.php :

   <?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

+- DOCROOT/.htaccess :

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1

+- DOCROOT/subdir/index.php :

   <?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

+- DOCROOT/.htaccess :

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1
```

With that setup, you can call `http://server/some-path` and see `/some-path` echoed back, or call `http://server/subdir/other-path` and see `/other-path` echoed back.

## Single `.htaccess`

You can also add the rewrite rule for the sub-directory in your main `.htaccess` file that is in the document root - just dup the last rewrite chain (the only one that is interesting) and add a `RewriteCond` to the *first* one that limits only to the sub directory.

Taking your example above, it might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(member-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))/?$ subdirectory/team.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(member-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))/?$ team.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

(I've also took the libery to remove the redundant `RewriteEngine On` command). If a request comes to the sub directory, it will be caught by the first rule, rewritten using the subdirectory context and the `[L]` flag will cause mod_rewrite stop processing. Otherwise it'll do the main routing. This setup is a bit too complex for my taste and I'd probably go with the additional .htaccess file.

Comment: do i have to add seperate htaccess file inside my sub directory?

Comment: Ahh.. I was assuming that you do, and removing the `RewriteBase` should be done on the sub-directory's `.htaccess`. You can actually add your rewrite rules for the sub-directory to the main directory. I've updated my answer with the details

Comment: whatever you assumed is correecgt, actually i have seperate htaccess file in sub directory, I removed `RewriteBase` command as you suggested but its not working. I prefer to keep htaccess seperate as my actual htaccess is quite long

Comment: can you please suggest how to keep separate htaccess inside sub folder

Comment: If you have a `.htaccess` in a subfolder, and requests that navigate into that subfolder will use that `.htaccess` and will not use the main `.htaccess`. You can verify this by commenting out the `RewriteCond` in the beta `.htaccess` and see that all requests redirect.

Comment: I added the htaccess file in beta as suggested in the answer, i.e by replacing subdirectory as beta, but it gives me 404-page not found. Also it seems that, 404 page is executed from root directory and not from /beta

Comment: I made some garbage entries to my htaccess file, still it gives 404 instead of internal server error, i think my beta/.htaccess is not getting used

Comment: I've added a detailed example of how to set up multiple .htaccess files. I've tested it and it works well on Apache 2.4.10 with a default setup

Comment: Thanks Guss, I will take a look tonight.